# Tracking with a Database

Tags: mysql, database

I'm not looking for the answer, I am just looking for some guidance or a little clarity here. I need to design a database as if I worked for redbox and I'm trying to track movies actors and directors. So I am assuming I need three different tables but I just don't understand how to "track" it. Would I create a custom ID for each movie and something that tracks where the kiosks are? Like I said, I think I can do this but I just fully understand it.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Your question is too broad, and you do not provide enough examples. EG: table example, more clarity about what you intend by "tracking" as well as what your code might look like.

Comment: I think you need to add a lot more of data, details, data examples, stuff like that so someone could imagine your scenario. The question is too general. Could you add any data you think is important to understand the big picture?

Comment: kiosk entity, location entity, movie entity, movie Attribute entity, attribute entity, customer entity, to name but a few.

Comment: If you think you can do it, then try it first and then came asking for help. Not the other way around. And if you want just opinion about your code go to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: All I meant by that is that I think I can create it I just don't know what all to include. Kinda hard to create it when youre in the dark.

Comment: if this is a homework, then ask your teacher. You should have a list of requirement already. Or maybe check that redbox site.

Comment: I would think the tables might be `movies`, `people` (for directors, actors, and crew), a linking table like `movie_people` (columns: movie_id, people_id), `kiosks`, and `kiosk_movies` (Columns: kiosk_id, movie_id)

Comment: Maybe you are confused, this isn't a teaching website.We help each other when have specific problems. But in your case the question is too broad and is very hard us to provide help if you don't provide enough information

Comment: Do you think I got my reputation by trolling others? I really try to help you guiding you on the right direction. First you didn't explain the goals of the project that is why I say check with your teacher so we have some guidelines.  And "do this for me" questions are really discourage here, other wise we will have people looking for free code and will ruin the propose of this site. Finally I suggested you try it first because that is how you learn programming face problems and trying to solve them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In broad strokes here is what you need:

(Basic relational rules and strategy apply, so every table needs to have a Primary Key, and the keys will be used to relate the tables together).

**movie:**
One row per movie, with title, rating, year, etc.

**person:**
Add to that a related person table with one row for any person who might be a cast or crew member in any film.

**credit:**, **credit_type**
Now relate Movie <-> Person
Since this is a many to many relationship you need a table between the two.  Typically this would be called "credit" and you need a credit_type table that will describe the credit (actor, director, writer, producer, etc).

Of course that has nothing to do with your "tracking" question.  For that you would need a slew of tables:

**inventory:**
Here is where you have one row for every copy of a movie that exists.  It should be obvious that there will be a foreign key for a movie in this table.  In the real world there would be an assigned id that would then be printed out as a barcode and attached to the disk + sleeve of the physical material.

**kiosk:**
For every Kiosk there is a row, along with location information, which could be an address perhaps along with a note, in case there are multiple kiosks at the same location.

**kiosk_bin:**
For every Kiosk, you will have a 1-M bins, each with a number identifying it.

I wouldn't do it this way, but you could for simplicity add a column in kiosk_bin that would be a foreign key to the inventory table.  In this way you are able to indicate that an inventory (a single copy of one particular movie) is sitting in a kiosk_bin.

**member:**
These are the people subscribed to the service.

**member_checkout:**
When a member gets a movie from a kiosk/kiosk_bin, a row gets created here, with the inventory_id, and the date, and the system would update the kiosk_bin row to remove the inventory_id and show that the bin is now empty and could accept another inventory copy.

As you can see, this is non-trivial.  Database design of any relatively complicated business process is going to be more than 3 tables, I'm sorry to say.

Here's an ERD that illustrates some of the basic movie to credit relations I did for another similar question.  The tables were named a bit differently but you should be able to match them up.

[image: Simple Movie ERD]